# VB6 ActiveX DLL expose forms IIS

Tags: iis, vb6, activex

Is it possible to call VB6 form through activex dll using ASP.net. I am able to call the activex dll (vb6) and test it locally with success. The DLL has a class that has From1.Show vbModal. When deploying the application IE just spins. I have registered the DLL as well. Any advice? Or can this not be completed?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 The form is shown in session 0, which is invisible to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, you simply cannot do what you are trying to do, unless you have access to the DLL source and can remove the use of Forms.